# strange token websites url

Tags: php, security, token

I always wonder what these very long numbers and alphabets are in URL as Get variables, I am using neat URLs and since my knowledge of security is not enough I start to feel worry. Would you please explain a little about these strange numbers in URLs ?

Example(From Phpmyadmin URL):

```
...PMA/index.php?db=dbname&token=a39db927509691755dc2e2ca463f42cd#PMAURL:db=noondreams&server=1&target=db_structure.php&token=a39db927509691755dc2e2ca463f42cd
```

Comment: The usage is not deferrable from the mix of symbols. You'll have to look at the source to tell what they're being used for. Might be session ids, might be nonces.

Comment: @mario why session IDS travel along URLs? Webser handle them? Doesn't it?

Comment: Cookies are only one way to transfer them. http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-trans-sid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the PhpMyAdmin case, the token is used to protect from CSRF. So, you should be more worried if there were none. :)

See documentation from PMP [here](https://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Security_Of_phpMyAdmin#CSRF_-_Cross_site_request_forgery) and a general description of CSRF [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery)